# How do i move the sprite while the finger is touching?

Tags: ios, touch, sprite-kit

I'm working on a small game to learn more xcode and objective-C.

I want to move my sprite along one axis while i am touching.
I know how to use SKAction with moveBy, but the sprite stops moving when it reaches the stated distance.

I want the sprite to move untill the touch ends. Currently i'm only moving it along the x axis.

Comment: Do you want to drag the sprite with your finger (like the knob of a `UISlider`)?  Or do you want the sprite to move at a constant velocity while your finger is touching the screen (like the cursor moves while I hold down an arrow key)?

Comment: At a constant velocity while the finger is touching. And stops when the finger is removed, i assume touchEnds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this.

Here's a simple one: in your `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, set a flag to `YES` in your scene indicating that the finger is down.  In `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, set the flag to `NO`.  In your scene's `update:` method, if the flag is `YES`, modify the sprite's position.

```
@implementation MyScene {
    BOOL shouldMoveSprite;
    SKNode *movableSprite;
    NSTimeInterval lastMoveTime;
}

 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    lastMoveTime = HUGE_VAL;
    shouldMoveSprite = YES;
}

 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    shouldMoveSprite = NO;
}

 - (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    shouldMoveSprite = NO;
}

static CGFloat kSpriteVelocity = 100;

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    NSTImeInterval elapsed = currentTime - lastMoveTime;
    lastMoveTime = currentTime;
    if (elapsed > 0) {
        CGFloat offset = kSpriteVelocity * elapsed;
        CGPoint position = movableSprite.position;
        position.x += offset;
        movableSprite.position = position;
    }
}
```

Another approach would be, when the touch begins, to attach a custom action (using `+[SKAction customActionWithDuration:block:]`) to the sprite that moves it a little bit, and to remove the action when the touch ends.

Another approach would be to use the physics engine.  When the touch begins, set the sprite's `physicsBody.velocity` to a non-zero vector (or apply an impulse).  When the touch ends, set the velocity back to `CGVectorMake(0,0)`.

Comment: Thank you!
Also, is there a reason to use YES and NO instead of false and true?
I'm used to use false and true.

Comment: `YES`, and `NO` are the conventional literals for `BOOL` in Objective-C, but `true` and `false` will work in most places too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did -- not sure if it's the most efficient method, but it works the way I want it to!

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.isFingerOnBowl)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        moveBowlToPoint = [SKAction moveToX:(touchLocation.x) duration:0.01];
        [_bowl runAction:moveBowlToPoint];
    }
}
```